# Cannot add view in .Net Core RC2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core-rc2

I am trying to add a scaffold mvc view in .Net Core RC2 but I get the error **"There is no entity type ClientsOverviewViewModel on DbContext RNW.Data.ApplicationDbContext"**.

[image: Add View to project]

With the view I want to display a list of Client.
My Client class:

```
public class Client : Person
{
    #region Personal Data 
    public Nationality Nationality { get; set; }
    public Confession Confession { get; set; }
    public string SSN { get; set; }
    public MaritalStatus MaritalStatus { get; set; }
    #endregion
    ...
}

    public class Person
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public Sex Sex { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public Address Birthplace { get; set; }
    public Address ResidentialAddress { get; set; }
    public string EMail { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

In the list I want to display 5 properties, which I have put into my ViewModel:

```
public class ClientsOverviewViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Nachname")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Vorname")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Geschlecht")]
    public Sex Sex { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Staatsbürgerschaft")]
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Geburtsdatum")]
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

Also here is my ApplicationDbContext Class:

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

I also get the same error, if I try to use Client instead of the viewmodel.

**Things I have tried so far:**

- Create a different DbContext class, which derives from DbContext (assumption here was, that IdentityDbContext might have an issue)
- Add a property `public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }`
- Add a property `public DbSet<ClientsOverviewViewModel> Clients { get; set; }` (which shouldn't be necessary but I thought I'll give it a try)
- Try different combination of template and model classes (besides Client and the viewmodel), without success

I haven't generated a DB yet, might that be an issue?
I am also using **entity framework core** in the **version 1.0.0-preview1-final**

**What I also have tried:**
I added a **TempDbContext which** derives from DbContext and just wanted to add the view with **Model class** Client and **Data context class** TempDbContext.
Then I get the error **"The item specified is not the element of a list"**

Sadly I was not able to find any blog posts or stackoverflow questions regarding my problem.

Comment: why the answer is not accepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ViewModel classes must have a key on it. A property named `Id` works fine.

Comment: this was a problem in my case, I had a typo in Id field name

Comment: I had a similar issue, I had a `public Uri Url { get; set; }` in my ViewModel. Apparently the code generation didn't like having a Uri type in there. The 'Code Generation Log' output in Visual studio did point me in the general direction after I read your answer that the ViewModel class might have issues.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had was EF does not support Generic List (List). Once I changed this I was able to use the scaffolding tools.